# How does a single file component pass context.data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I loop functional components in the `transition-group`, and because I didn't pass a key reference to the root element of the tag component to the tag component.

But how does a single file component pass the `context.data`?

The sample link
https://codesandbox.io/s/rjjmpvwm4n/

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<tag>` component needs a `key` to use as its child `<span>`'s id.

Since `<tag>` is a [**functional component**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components), you will have to access to the data via the `data.` prefix.

So, since you are using `<tag v-for="item in list" :key="item"></tag>`, inside the `<tag>`'s template, **you can access the `key` (of `context.data`) automatically using `data.key`**:

- Add `:key="data.key"` in **tag.vue**:

  ```html
    <template functional>
      <span :key="data.key">tag content</span>
    </template>
  ```

**Demo CodeSandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/wxmvxnojl?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Ftag.vue